# Did you try nesting Schemas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to populate from another collection.

its throw me an error like that :

> TypeError: Undefined type `C` at `0`   Did you try nesting Schemas?
>   You can only nest using refs or arrays.

My code :

```
const ProductsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    price: {
        type: Number
    },
    category: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'categories'
    }]
});
```

tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Nvm , the problem was in another link.
syntax issue.